# if i use custom category for custom posts its single page shows 404 error else it's working good in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

```
<?php
/**
 * Updates Module custom post type
 */
add_action('init', 'packages_post_type_register');
function packages_post_type_register() {
    register_post_type( 'packages' ,
                        array(
                            'label' => 'Packages',
                            'singular_label' => 'Packages',
                            'public' => true,
                            'show_ui' => true,
                            //'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/testimonials-icon.png', 
                            'capability_type' => 'post',
                            'hierarchical' => false,
                            'rewrite' => true,
                            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                            'supports' => array('title','thumbnail', 'editor')
                        )
                    );
    add_filter('manage_edit-packages_columns', 'packages_edit_columns');
    function packages_edit_columns($columns){
        $columns = array(
            'cb'    => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'title' => 'packages',
            'author'=> 'Author',
            'date'  =>'Date'
        );
        return $columns;
    }
}
?>
<?php
/* Set up the taxonomies. */ 
add_action( 'init', 'packages_taxonomies', 0);
/* Registers taxonomies. */
function packages_taxonomies() { 
    /* Set up the artist taxonomy arguments. */ 
    $category_args = array( 
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,

    'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'packages'),
    'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Category',
    'singular_name' => 'Category',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Category',
                    'update_item' => 'Update Category',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
                    'new_item_name' => 'New Category',
                    'all_items' => 'All Categories',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Category',
                    'parent_item' => 'Parent Category',
                    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Category:',
                    ),
    );

    /* Register the technology taxonomy. */
    register_taxonomy( 'packages_category', array( 'packages'), $category_args );
    /* Adds the post_tag taxonomy to the page post type. */
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'packages'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Try flushing permalink.

Answer (score 0):

Slug for post type and taxonomy is same please change the slug for taxonomy...
Sorry initially I did not checked your code.

Comment: it snot working

Comment: Oh I just checked your code and I noticed that slug for post type and taxonomy is same please use different slug for taxonomy may be packages-cats